# Calling a function that was passed through its props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently new to react-bootstrap and have a question i can not solve.

I want to set my parents state by passing it as a prop to its child. Whe ncalling the function it seems to be executed, but the state is not set.. I have no clue why that is.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            component : ""
        }

        this.returnDashboard = this.returnDashboard.bind(this);
    }


    returnDashboard=()=>{
        console.log("i am executed")
        this.setState({component : <Dashboard />})
    }

    render(){           
        return (
            <Child returnDashboard={this.returnDashboard}/>
        );
    }
};


class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
         return(
                <button onClick={()={this.props.returnSettings()}}>foo</button>
            );
    }
}
```

when pressing the button the console logs "i am executed" and this: ƒ () { [native code] }. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo

```
onClick={()={this.props.returnSettings()}}
```

Should be

```
onClick={() => this.props.returnSettings()}
```

Or even simpler

```
onClick={this.props.returnSettings}
```

Comment: thank you, i didn`t see the typo. Besides that there actually was another mistake in my code. Everything works fine now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you note have a returnSettings props in child component, 
do click event like this

onClick = {()=>this.props.returnDashboard}